# wxPython - Can't get buttons to resize

Tags: wxpython

I am new to wxPython and I have a very basic question about getting buttons to resize.

Im working on a mac with python 2.7.3 and using wxPython 2.8.10.1

I have been working with it for a few days and I think I understand the sizer layout methods.  I am trying to get a grid of buttons to grow in size when the window is expanded.  I know its a basic issue but I have spent hours.

I cant figure out how to get a screen shot image here but the buttons show fine and then stay the same size when the window is enlarged.

Thanks.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import wx
class Example(wx.Frame):

def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
    super(Example, self).__init__(*args, **kw) 
    self.InitUI()
    self.SetSize((550, 160))
    self.SetTitle("Label of Grids")
    self.Centre()
    self.Show()     

def InitUI(self):

    pnl = wx.Panel(self)       
    grid = wx.GridBagSizer(3, 3)
    for r in range(6):
        for c in range (4):
            buttonname = str(r)+"_"+str(c)
            labeltxt = "(row= "+str(r)+", col= "+str(c)+")"
            grid.Add(wx.Button(pnl, name = buttonname,label=labeltxt), (r, c),flag =wx.EXPAND)
    pnl.SetSizer(grid)

def main():

    app = wx.App()
    Example(None)
    app.MainLoop()    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using `GridBagSizer`'s you need to make calls to the `AddGrowableCol(idx)` and `AddGrowableRow(idx)` methods in order to allow individual rows and columns in the Grid to be fluid in size.

Comment: I had thought of that by adding these:
    grid.AddGrowableRow(r)
    grid.AddGrowableCol(c)
This makes the rows and cols grow but not the buttons

Comment: The AddGrowable methods enable the cells to expand, but you still need to use the wx.EXPAND flag on the items to get them to expand to fill the grid cell.  You should also look at using the WIT to help experiment with options and visualize what is happening with sizers.  http://wiki.wxpython.org/Widget_Inspection_Tool

Comment: @NewatPython - You'll need a combination like Robin pointed out.  I posted it because the necessary calls weren't in your example code.  If you've used both, and it's still not working, we need to see more complete code to figure out what's going on.

Comment: I will give this a shot tomorrow and will use the WIT. Thanks.

Comment: This worked.  Thank you @g.d.d.c and thank you Robin for the WIT.  Robin I'm working through your book with examples.  I'm sure I'll have some questions for both of you going forward.